# Applescript, OS X : How to Get a list of phone numbers from Contacts, and send an iMessage with Messages App? Halfway there I think..?

Tags: applescript, messages, contacts

I am trying to create an applescript that will grab all of the **labeled** phone numbers of 'mobile' and 'iPhone' from the **every** contact in Contacts App (specifically the phone numbers from the iCloud account), and then send an iMessage or SMS to them using Messages App.

I think I have a good part of it, but I get 2 errors that I can't seem to understand.

```
tell application "Contacts"
    repeat with eachContact in (get every person)
        repeat with eachPhoneNum in (get phones of eachContact)
if label of eachPhoneNum is "mobile" or "iPhone" then
            delay 2

            tell application "Messages"
                set myid to get id of first service
                set theBuddy to buddy eachPhoneNum of service id myid
                send theMessage to theBuddy
            end tell
end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

**Corrected Error 1**: `Contacts got an error: Can’t get label.` As script is above.

Still experiencing Error 2: `Can’t make «class az20» 1 of «class azf4» id "89E7AF18-A017-4119-B788-CBB96571FAAE:ABPerson" of application "Contacts" into the expected type.`

Comment: Could you try to make a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on the problem that you are facing with the smallest amount of code possible?

Comment: @grgarside - Updated. The previous code was a verifiable, complete, working example, but I am more than happy to clean it up to make it 'minimal'. Thanks :)

Comment: As of error 1, you're getting phone label 'mobile' and label 'iPhone '. Can't try it out right now as I'm on iOS...

Comment: @NikoNyman Yes, when I strip out the label criteria, I get a `class error` that it `can't convert the type`. I am assuming this means that it can't convert the result of `phone` into the variable `eachPhoneNum`and needs some kind of conversion.. But I even tried adding `as text` to convert it, and I still get the error.

Comment: I was a bit unclear previously: have you tried `...whose phone label is "mobile" or phone label is "iPhone"`? To me it looks like you're getting the first error from trying to access `label "iPhone"` and (I assume) the property is called `phone label`.

Comment: I've corrected the label area after 3 more hours of googling. It appears you can't pull LABEL inline, you have to parse it out afterward. But I'm still not able to get the phone number from each contact.